# Обмен данными между Telegram ботом и Webapp

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, web-apps

Пытаюсь разобраться с Web приложениями для ботов в Telegram. В качестве библиотеки использую telegraf.js (nodejs).

Что мне нужно: я хочу открыть web приложение по нажатию кнопки в inline_keyboard. При открытии мне надо передать некоторые данные в web приложение, затем в приложении их обработать и вызвать функцию в коде бота, в которую необходимо передать обработанные данные.

**Передачу данных в Webapp можно сделать через параметры URL, но как быть с чувствительной информацией, которую не следует передавать в GET?**

В документации (https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-web-apps) сказано, что для передачи данных из Webapp назад в бота, следует использовать метод window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData. Но вместе с этим сказано: This method is only available for Web Apps launched via a Keyboard button. То есть при запуске из кнопки inline_keyboard этот метод работать не будет. **Так каким же образом мне передать данные?**

Можно конечно поднять свой http сервер, по нажатию кнопки в Webapp посылать на него запрос и как-то его обрабатывать... Но это такие костыли. Неужели пашка правда дурень и не сделал что-то поудобнее?

**Буду благодарен КРАСИВЫМ и ЛАКОНИЧНЫМ примерам кода.**

Comment: Ваше предположение, _Неужели пашка правда дурень..._  недалеко от правды. На [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/666278/#comment_24357552) есть забавное обсуждение работы этих новых веб-приложений. И отвечая на ваш вопрос, на данный момент запуск через `inline-button` и отправка данных обратно боту работает только через костыли в виде собственного веб-сервера.